# Send values with contact form 7 wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, contacts

I have a form having fields like this.

```
<form action="http://localhost/brands/?page_id=14" method="get">
                            <p>
                            <label>*Graphic Size:</label>
                            <select name="size">
                                <option>6X6</option>
                            </select>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                            <label>*Frame Color:</label>
                            <select name="color">
                                <option>Silver</option>
                                <option>Gold</option>
                            </select>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                            <label>Quantity:</label>
                            <input name="quantity" class="quantity" class="number" type="number" value="10" />
                            </p>
                            <p style="width:100%;">
                            <a href="#"><span style="background:#447838; padding:5px 20px;">Get Quote</span></a>
                            </p>
                            </form>
```

**Question:** 
I want to send these values with contact form 7.

```
$_GET['size'];
$_GET['color'];
$_GET['quantity'];
```

contact form 7 have these fields.

```
From: [your-name] <[your-email]>
Subject: [your-subject]
Subject: [Company]
Subject: [Phone]
```

Comment: what do you mean you want to send those values? also you're missing the name attribute for the quantity input

Comment: I have these custom fields and send them with contact form 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea what the two relationships are, but you shouldn't be hard coding those fields inside of a CF7 form object. Instead, add them properly, and hook into the `wpcf7_before_send_mail` method from within your `functions.php` file.

```
function pre_process_fields(){
    $size = $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['size'];
    $color = $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['color'];
    $quantity = $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['quantity'];

    //do something with them?
}

add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'pre_process_fields');
```

Hopefully this gives you some clarity.